# Java - how should a method with return treat exceptions

Tags: java, exception, methods

I'm doing some exercises about Exception Handling and nothing is working. I'd like to know how a method with return should implement a exception, for instance:

```
public class Class{
double n1, n2, result;

public double sum(double n1, double n2){
  this.n1 = n1;
  this.n2 = n2;
  result = n1 + n2;

  return result;
}


}
```

This would b e the class and method, then..What if i want to make a exception that makes sure no letters will be input (the Scanner would be in the main class).

I tried the following code:

public double sum(double n1, double n2){

```
    try{

        this.n1 = n1;
        this.n2 = n2;
        result = n1 + n2;

    }catch(NumberFormatException e){

        System.out.println("Error!");
        return 0;
    }

    return result;

}
```

But whenever i execute this and input a letter, the following error occurs:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2456)
at lista05excecoes.Principal.main(Principal.java:17)
Java Result: 1
```

When i wanted it to output only the message ERROR

Comment: **Read** the stack trace of the exception. It has nothing to do with the code you posted. The exception is thrown by `Scanner.nextDouble()`, used in `Principal.main()`. The posted code doesn't use any Scanner.

Comment: Your question is very confusing, because you're clearly calling `nextDouble` somewhere... but not in the code you've shown.

Comment: I declared the nextDouble, Scanner and stuff on the main method. What should i do to fix this error and make sure the Sum method can handle the non-numeric input exception? The exercise is about making the Methods (sum, subtract, divide and multiplication) handle the non-numeric input exceptions. What should i do to make it work then? I just used Scanner on the main class to test if it would work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have shown isn't responsible for throwing the exception; it can only calculate the sum.

From your stack trace, your `main` method contains the code that throws the exception, by using a `Scanner`.  The `Scanner` found non-numeric input and threw the exception.  Place your try/catch block around the `nextDouble` method, not your code that sums the 2 numbers.

Comment: Oh i see, Thank you. But what changes should i make to make sure the sum method can handle the non-numeric exception? Since the exercise is about making the sum, subtract, multiply and divide methods handling the non-numeric input

Comment: The `sum` method is already taking `double`s.  By the time this method is called, any non-numeric output has already been caught.  When this method is called, the input has already been verified as numeric input and converted to `double`s.  The `sum` method doesn't need to verify that the input was `double`; its only job is to add numbers that have already been converted to `double`s.

Answer (score 0):

The exception that is being thrown is not the same as the input you are trying to catch. That is why it is printing the whole thing rather than just "error".

Additionally, if you are adding the two variables together why do you need to store them?